# CRUD operations on multiple tables in a single class

Tags: c#, sql, class, crud

I have problems. I'm working on AdventureWorks2012 database. from single class to multiple tables, insert-update-delete-list operations have to do. How could this be? multiple tables and within tables in different numbers and different from each other's variables. how is this possible?

I'm new to c # . please help.

http://www.schorkenterprises.com/images/AdventureWorks2008.png

Comment: what did you tried so far, why a single class?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: I would suggest you to break down the class to more simpler small classes. As you are new to c#, you can focus on learning object oriented practices. That will help you in long run.

quick example to resolve your problem:

Suppose, you have a Student class, which has a ID, Name, Section, Address. Suppose You have some tables in db called: Student, Address, Section. If i were you, i would break down the Student class into Student, Address, Section.

Suppose, Section table has fields:Id, Section name, StudentID in db.

and Address table has fields: ID, Address, City, Country, Zip code, StudentID.

So, how the new class will look like?

1. Student class will hold: ID, Name, Section Object, Address Object.
2. Section class will hold(as db requires): Id, Section name, StudentID
3. Address class will hold(as db requires): ID, Address, City, Country,
   Zip code, StudentID

when you will fetch Student from db, you will fetch section and address object for that student. For saving and updating data, the process will be somewhat same.

I hope this writing will give  you a brief, what you will have to do.

have a nice day